# Table image in cell shown smaller

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm having trouble. I upgraded a Joomla 1.5 to 2.5.7. Imported all the content as well. 
Some articles are built using HTML TABLE tag, rows, and 2 columns. Text in first column, image with correct HEIGHT/WIDTH attribute is in the second column.

See this page:

http://stageseminars.com/index.php/2012-10-24-18-26-22/how-to-tech/paperwork/108-lighting-board-notes

In FireFox, it's rendered beautifully, in Chrome, IE9, and Safari, **the image is resized smaller**, leaving too much space for the text that could be wrapped up more.

In the J15 version of the site, it was fine.

I tried playing with the CSS a bit last night, the best I could do to get the full size of image had the image showing offset way out of the table, and event the main-content container, played with min-width/max-width, percentage, even forced the px (I don't like it because maybe in the future the client would use different image size)

There's multiple articles like, I know this could be converted tableless somehow, style templating. But there's a better and faster way, I would appreciate it!

Please advise! If you need any more information, let me know as well.

Comment: try removing: max-width:100% for those images, it's been applied to all images in template.css - line 11

Comment: ! HEY! wow, It fixed for Chrome, and Safari. IE9 is still unhappy.

Comment: What about removing the next parameter: height:auto for those images ?

Comment: Bloody hell, the effort us web developers have to go to, to make sites work in IE lol.

Comment: That's a nice shot but now the ratio is bad, I get proper Height but the Width doesn't follow !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the css modifications dicussed in the comments, there is a function in `http://stageseminars.com/templates/rt_kirigami/js/modules-height.js`
that sets some styles for your images on IE9 and IE10.

```
        'load': function(){
        if (Browser.ie9 || Browser.ie10){
            document.getElements('img').each(function(img){
                img.setStyle('max-width', img.getStyle('width').toInt() || img.offsetWidth);
                img.setStyle('width', '100%');
            });
        }
```

You can comment it, I already tested it on IE9 (removing that function) and it works !

Comment: Thank you very much! this is solved as far as I know :)